# Python regex for multiple search inputs

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to create a regex expression but facing some issue

```
test33 = "ID : 11111111   ID2 : 0  "

v = re.findall(r'ID :..|ID :.........|ID2 :..'
               , test33)
for x in v:
    print(x)
output -- ID : 1 
          ID2 : 0
required output = ID : 11111111
```

Here in my search string ID can be 0 or some digits sometimes , the issue is in my regex if I m defining to check for both condition & the string ID val is in multiple still it validates for first condition only

> i.e ID :.

& displays the result how can I fix it to achieve output for both   ID : 11111111 or ID:0

Answer (score 0):

```
re.findall("ID : \d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d")
```

Comment: thanks yusuf but this only works when the ID val is 11111111 but if it is less than it it wont return result for ID : 11 = no match

Comment: re.findall("ID : \d?\d?\d?\d?\d?\d?\d?\d", idText)

Answer (score 0):

You can match optional digits after ID and match 1 or more digits after the colon.

Note that the `.` matches any character and in your pattern it matches the exact amount.

```
\bID\d*\s*:\s*\d+
```

- `\bID` Match ID preceded by a word boundary `\b` to prevent a partial match
- `\d*` Match 0+ digits
- `\s*:\s*` Match `:` between optional whitespace chars
- `\d+` Match 1+ digits

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KCoudn/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/2DdBWd)

```
import re
 
test33 = "ID : 11111111   ID2 : 0  "
v = re.findall(r'\bID\d*\s*:\s*\d+', test33)
 
print(v)
```

Output

```
['ID : 11111111', 'ID2 : 0']
```

Comment: is there any flag like \d+ to search for string as well ?

Comment: @Lp-Tester You could use `\w+` to match 1 or more word characters, or use `\S+` to match 1 or more non whitespace characters.

Comment: @lyon You unchecked the mark as answer. Did it not work?